# Makefile to generate JSON from Python scripts in separate directories

Tags: shell, makefile

I have a Makefile which generates JSON from several different Python scripts (the scripts print to stdout) in a single directory, e.g.

```
/src
    scriptOne.py
    scriptTwo.py
    scriptThree.py
```

Which outputs the JSON to a folder:

```
/templates
   scriptOne.json
   scriptTwo.json
   scriptThree.json
```

I'm trying to restructure so that, for example, each script is in its own subdirectory and the Makefile creates the JSON templates in their consequent subdirectories as follows:

```
/src
   /importantTemplates
       scriptOne.py 
   /notSoImportantTemplates
       scriptTwo.py
       scriptThree.py
```

And the output:

```
/templates
   /importantTemplates
       scriptOne.json 
   /notSoImportantTemplates
       scriptTwo.json
       scriptThree.json
```

The current Makefile is as follows:

```
SOURCES := $(shell echo src/*.py)
TARGETS := $(patsubst src/%.py,templates/%.json,$(SOURCES))

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS)

templates/%.json: src/%.py
    python2 $< > $@
```

I've tried changing the wildcards to include a subdirectory for each line e.g. `/src/*/*.py`, although I just end up with the following:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a static pattern rule ([4.12 Static Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)) for this.

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*/*.py)
TARGETS := $(patsubst src/%.py,templates/%.json,$(SOURCES))

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
        rm -rf templates

$(TARGETS) : templates/%.json: src/%.py
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        python2 $< > $@
```

You could avoid needing `mkdir -p` in that rule body if you wanted to (and go with an order-only prerequisite on the directory instead) but I'm not sure the effort is worth the savings in execution cost. You could avoid the extra shell by combining the two lines `mkdir -p $(@D) && python2 $< > $@` if you wanted to though.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the second time you run the make, it will give you the message (if there are no new files):

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Try to run make clean and see if you get the same message.

Here is the Makefile which will do what you want:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*/*.py)
TARGETS := $(patsubst src/%.py,templates/%.json,$(SOURCES))
FOLDERS := $(sort $(dir $(TARGETS)))

all: $(TARGETS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGETS) $(FOLDERS)

$(FOLDERS):
    mkdir -p $@

$(TARGETS): $(SOURCES) $(FOLDERS)
    python2 $< > $@
```

The FOLDERS variable will contain the folders you need to create in the template directory. (sort will remove duplicates, so each folder will be there only once)

The $(FOLDERS) rule will create the folders.
The clean rule will remove the folders also.

If you need to add more sources, just do it like this:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*/*.py)
SOURCES += $(wildcard src/*.py)
...
```

Comment: `$(FOLDERS)` should be an order-only prerequisite, thus you can drop the `-p` flag from `mkdir` command. `rm -rf` should be `$(RM) -r`. `$(patsubst src/%.py,templates/%.json,$(SOURCES))` could be `$(SOURCES:src/%.py=templates/%.json)`. And `SOURCES` could use `$(shell find ...)`.

Comment: @Chnossos Why would you recommend `$(shell)` over `$(wildcard)`? `-f` on the clean target means it won't ever fail (which it will when run twice in a row otherwise).

Comment: This makes every output json file depend on *every* input python file. You want a static pattern rule instead of that `$(TARGETS): $(SOURCES)` rule. `$(TARGETS) : templates/%.json : src/%.py` or something like that.